# Add average of running total to running total until the end of the year

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, addition

I am trying to analyse some historical data and then use this historical data to forecast a projected future count of values.

I have a running total on my data that is correctly producing the average information per week until the end of the valid data. I am then linking this to a calendar table, this then shows the remaining weeks of the year.

**I am wanting to take an average of the current year and then add this via a compound interest calculation to the previous data, until the end of the current year.**

A table of example output is shown below. The average value is only shown in this table to represent the average which is being added to the value column. The final table has 52/53 rows, one of each week of the year.

While the below average value of 23,055 is very large and does look strange to add onto the final value, in the full year the average of all values is 683, so provides a more gradual increase of the final average.

| Week | Value | Average | Final Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 31 | 21136 |  | 21136 |
| 32 | 21896 |  | 21896 |
| 33 | 22661 |  | 22661 |
| 34 | 23585 |  | 23585 |
| 35 | 24433 |  | 24433 |
| 36 | 24620 |  | 24620 |
| 37 |  | 23055 | 47675 |
| 38 |  | 23055 | 70730 |
| 39 |  | 23055 | 93786 |
| 40 |  | 23055 | 116841 |

I am using the following SQL code to produce a running count for the current calendar year to date:

```sql
SELECT 
    count(policynumber) as policies,
    DATEPART(WEEK, DATEADD(DAY, 7-(DATEPART(WEEKDAY, issuedate)), issuedate)) as  weekofyear,
    year(issuedate) as year,
    sum(count(policynumber)) OVER (PARTITION BY year(issuedate) ORDER BY DATEPART(WEEK, DATEADD(DAY, 7-(DATEPART(WEEKDAY, issuedate)), issuedate))) as Running_Count
FROM 
    insure
where
year(issuedate) in (select max(year(issuedate)) as year from insure) and policyname like ('%contents%')

group by year(issuedate),DATEPART(WEEK, DATEADD(DAY, 7-(DATEPART(WEEKDAY, issuedate)), issuedate))
```

This produces the following output:

| Year | Week | Value | Running Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022 | 1 | 5 | 5 |
| 2022 | 2 | 422 | 427 |
| 2022 | 3 | 604 | 1031 |
| 2022 | 4 | 715 | 1746 |
| 2022 | 5 | 704 | 2450 |
| 2022 | 6 | 761 | 3211 |

I then match this data to a calendar table which contains all of the weeks for a year. When a week exists in both queries the value from the above query is shown, where it doesn't exist in both queries a null value is shown

i.e.

| Year | Week | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022 | 34 | 23585 |
| 2022 | 35 | 24433 |
| 2022 | 36 | 24623 |
| 2022 | 37 | 0 |
| 2022 | 38 | 0 |
| 2022 | 39 | 0 |
| 2022 | 40 | 0 |

In my full query (shown at the end of the question) when the week value is a future week, I am wanting to take the last value from the value column and then add to it the average of the values to that point in time i.e.

- week 37 should be 24623+683 = 25303 (last value + average of total value column)
- week 38 should be 24623+683+683=25986
- week 39 should be 24623+683+683+683=26669
- week 40 should be 24623+683+683+683+683=27352
- this should continue until week 52/53

The Insure table has the following setup:

| policynumber | policyname | issuedate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Contents | 2022-05-06 |
| 2 | Contents | 2022-06-06 |
| 3 | Contents | 2022-06-07 |
| 4 | Contents | 2022-07-08 |

The full query is below, in this query the Test Column is a compound interest calculation of all values in the value column plus the average of the values from the value column, in effect double counting the information.

This query produces the following output

| Year | Week | Value | Test |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022 | 31 | 21136 | 0 |
| 2022 | 32 | 21896 | 0 |
| 2022 | 33 | 22661 | 0 |
| 2022 | 34 | 23585 | 0 |
| 2022 | 35 | 24433 | 0 |
| 2022 | 36 | 24620 | 0 |
| 2022 | 37 |  | 437473 |
| 2022 | 38 |  | 438156 |
| 2022 | 39 |  | 438839 |
| 2022 | 40 |  | 439522 |

**I am only wanting the test column to be populated with the value from the previous value field where a value in the value column doesn't exist plus the average of the full value column.**

```sql
select
subg.year,
subg.weekofyear,
subg.running_count,
case
    when subg.average=subg.running_count then 
        sum(subg.running_count) OVER (PARTITION BY subg.year ORDER BY subg.weekofyear) else 0 end as test
from(
/*Returns full year dates with year to date results*/
SELECT distinct
      DATEPART(WEEK, DATEADD(DAY, 7-(DATEPART(WEEKDAY, cal.date)), cal.date)) as  weekofyear
    , cal.year
    , syear.average
    , case when ins.Running_Count is null then syear.average else ins.Running_Count end as running_count
FROM
    LOOKUP_CALENDAR cal left outer join
    (SELECT 
    count(policynumber) as policies,
    DATEPART(WEEK, DATEADD(DAY, 7-(DATEPART(WEEKDAY, issuedate)), issuedate)) as  weekofyear,
    year(issuedate) as year,
    sum(count(policynumber)) OVER (PARTITION BY year(issuedate) ORDER BY DATEPART(WEEK, DATEADD(DAY, 7-(DATEPART(WEEKDAY, issuedate)), issuedate))) as Running_Count
FROM 
    insure
where
year(issuedate) in (select max(year(issuedate)) as year from insure) and policyname like ('%contents%')

group by year(issuedate),DATEPART(WEEK, DATEADD(DAY, 7-(DATEPART(WEEKDAY, issuedate)), issuedate))
    ) ins on ins.weekofyear= DATEPART(WEEK, DATEADD(DAY, 7-(DATEPART(WEEKDAY, cal.date)), cal.date)) left outer join
/*Returns Current year to date values*/
    (select
sub.sub_year,
avg(sub.policies) as average
from
(
SELECT 
year(issuedate) as sub_year,
      count(policynumber) as policies
FROM 
    insure
where
year(issuedate)  in (select max(year(issuedate)) as year from INS_MERGE_1) and
policyname like ('%contents%')
group by year(issuedate),DATEPART(WEEK, DATEADD(DAY, 7-(DATEPART(WEEKDAY, issuedate)), issuedate))) sub

group by sub.sub_year) syear on syear.sub_year=cal.year
/*Returns Current year to date values*/
where 
    cal.year in (select max(year(issuedate)) as year from insure)) as subg
/*Returns full year dates with year to date results*/
```

The following table contains an output of the tab subg as requested by @monofuse

| Year | WeekofYear | Average | Running Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022 | 1 | 683 | 5 |
| 2022 | 2 | 683 | 427 |
| 2022 | 3 | 683 | 1031 |
| 2022 | 4 | 683 | 1746 |
| 2022 | 5 | 683 | 2450 |
| ---- | ------------ | --------- | ------------------ |
| 2022 | 35 | 683 | 24433 |
| 2022 | 36 | 683 | 24620 |
| 2022 | 37 | 683 | 0 |
| 2022 | 38 | 683 | 0 |
| 2022 | 39 | 683 | 0 |
| 2022 | 40 | 683 | 0 |
| 2022 | 41 | 683 | 0 |

Comment: If you can create a [mre] emphasis in minimal, you will make it much easier for people to assist. As it is it's too complex for many people to spend the time to understand

Comment: I've updated the question to try and make it similar, but also leaving the original query in to show the current attempted solution

Comment: Dump the table subg with SELECT * into a table for us. I tried refactoring to get a working example but spent too much time on styling. I think your issue is the sum near the beginning, you probably want a lead over rather than a sum. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lead-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16